# iOS iPhone - get UIKeyboard height BEFORE keyboardWillShow

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, height, uikeyboard

I am aware that I can get the UIKeyboard height from UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey on the keyboardWillShow and keyboardDidShow notifications triggered when it becomes a first responder.

HOWEVER, I would like to know the expected height of a keyboard before these events so I can setup certain design elements at viewDidLoad of a view controller.

Since devices are changing and the new spell correction bar changes the keyboard height I do NOT want to hard code the height.

Does anyone know how to get the expected height from the keyboard taking into account whether it has auto-correct or not etc?

Comment: What exactly do you need it for? Be specific because you almost certainly want to take a different approach.

Comment: Note the part of my question that says "I would like to know the expected height of a keyboard before these events so I can setup certain design elements at viewDidLoad of a view controller". To expand on this: I have elements that are layed out based on the height of the keyboard but not in response to it's being raised.

Comment: You can't know beforehand. The keyboard height could be different for each text field or text view on the screen. One might have an `inputAccessoryView` and another might not.

Comment: Basically if I setup a textfield/view in IB or programaticcally it would be nice to have something like textField.inputView.frame.size.height . In the mean time I have settled for workarounds but they ultimately have lead to my design not looking exactly like I want due to the quicktype bar which does not exist before iOS8 and who knows what will change in the future.. I could mare responsive adjustments be determining the device and os but it's annoying and again is subject to future changes on the part of Apple

Answer (score 0):

You can do by the following way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self initializeTextView];
```

}
    -(void)initializeTextView{

```
// Listen for keyboard appearances and disappearances
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

myColoredTextview  = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 100)];
myColoredTextview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:myColoredTextview];
myColoredTextview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
// Do something here
 NSLog(@"show:%@",notif);
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [notif valueForKey:@"userInfo"];
 CGRect kbFrame = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue];
 NSLog(@"keboardHeight:%f",kbFrame.size.height);
```

}

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
// Do something here
NSLog(@"hide:%@",notif);
```

}